# What "the ceiling was too high to make out," means

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I was reading Harry Potter and the Philopher Stone when I came across this sentence

**"the ceiling was too high to make out,"**

What does **"make out"** stood for in this context? (In this part of the book, the physical structures of Hogwarts were being described)

Comment: ***Make out:*** Discern or see, especially with difficulty, as in *I can hardly make out the number on the door.* https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+out

Answer (score 4):

It means that the ceilings were too far away to be clearly (if at all) seen. The ceilings were so far away that they could not be distinguished or recognized with the naked eye as ceilings.

Comment: Thank you very much :)